# Pull content from a remote WordPress install

Tags: php, json, wordpress, feed

I need to create a wp widget that automatically pulls data from another wordpress install on a remote server.

Basically, the source site is a review site where offers vary over time. My widget will pull certain offers and make sure they stay updated.

Reviews on the source site are custom post types with custom meta fields that need to be fetched (price, offer, etc).

Looking around I've seen different suggestions: query the remote db, fetch the feed (does it store custom meta fields?), use json (which I barely know what is, but I am willing to learn new stuff).

What is the best method for my purpose and where can I find resources to help me achieving my goal?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Does the source site has an rss feed with offers?

Comment: It is a wordpress site, so has its own feed. I will have to see how to create a specific rss for offers.

Answer (score 1):

WordPress allows you to [have an RSS feed per custom post type](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-make-a-separate-rss-feed-for-each-custom-post-type-in-wordpress/) which is handy. Then you can make use of the WordPress [Fetch Feed function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/fetch_feed) to scoop what you need!

Comment: Thanks ArleyM. Looks like the best solution. I will have to play with it a bit and see what is the best way to implement this. Now, does SimplePie rss items also store custom meta fields? How will I be able to get them?

Comment: Alright. I managed to add my custom meta fields to the rss feed following this tips [link](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3801/add-custom-fields-to-custom-post-type-rss). I tried to print_r the simplePie object and they are there buried inside a ton of other stuff. I can see them in this form: [metaFields] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [data] => Array ( [0] => *lotsOfOtherStuff* ... Now how do I use them?

Comment: Unfortunately this is getting a bit out of my league too! Sounds like it would be worth posting as a new Question here or on the wordpress.stackexchange.com! 

One thing I've had success with was modifying this as a page template: http://yoast.com/custom-rss-feeds-wordpress/ - I was able to use the WP function get_the_post_thumbnail() in the foreach. Perhaps you can get meta data in there, and recycle some of this! 

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Are you the creator of the remote website?

- You can create a new template in your theme
- Code what you want to display in the format you want to display it
  (json or just a bit of html)
- In your wordpress admin create a new page and assign the new template
  to it.
- In your new site you just have to fetch the page

Comment: Yes I am. I don't think I understand your solution, here. How should I fetch the remote page?

Comment: or if you prefer to work with html, you can use this library:  [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)